# #1054 - La columna 'status' en field list es desconocida

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Este Stored procedure me da error cuando lo ejecuto en php myadmin

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_ModificarParametro`
( IN `nIdStatus` INT(11), IN `sNombreParametro` VARCHAR(100),  
IN `sValorParametro` VARCHAR(150), IN `dFechaCreacionParametro` DATE, 
IN `dFechaModificacionParametro` DATETIME, OUT `resultado` VARCHAR(200))

BEGIN

DECLARE verificarUno INT;


DECLARE verificarDos INT;

select  nIdStatus  into verificarUno 

from tstatus where nIdStatus  = status ;       


select  nIdStatus into verificarDos 
from tparametro  where nIdStatus = status ;




if(status > 0  and verificarUno is null ) then
 set resultado =`estatus de oficina invalida`  ;   end if;

if(status > 0  and verificarDos is null ) then
 set resultado =`estatus de oficina invalida`  ;   end if;

if  ( status > 0 ) then


UPDATE tparametro  SET  nIdStatus = status
 where nIdStatus=status;

end if; 


if !( nombreParametro =" ") then

UPDATE tparametro  SET  sNombreParametro= nombreParametro where nIdStatus=status;

end if;   

if  (valorParametro>0 ) then

UPDATE tparametro  SET  sValorParametro= valorParametro where nIdStatus=status;

end if;


if  (fechaCreacionParametro>0 ) then

UPDATE tparametro  SET  dFechaCreacionParametro = fechaCreacionParametro where nIdStatus=status;


end if;


if  (fechaModificacionParametro>0 ) then

UPDATE tparametro  SET dFechaModificacionParametro = fechaModificacionParametro where nIdStatus=status;

end if;

select "modificacion exitosa" into resultado ;

END$$


DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Como podemos ayudarte sin saber nada de nada de tu base de datos? el error es claro, esa columna no existe..

Answer (score 0):

Chequea que en las tablas (tsstatus y tparametro) donde se menciona la columna status en las consultas del stored proc se encuentre efectivamente una columna con el nombre status.